# Curl is nor printing while executing remotely using Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

The below code is not printing anything. Please let me know what is wrong with the script.

```
import paramiko

ip='ip'
port=22
username='userid'
password='passwd'

cmd="""curl https://www.facebook.com"""

try:
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)
    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    outlines=stdout.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    print(resp)

except:
    print("failed on login.")
```

Comment: Check `stderr`. Also remove the try except as it's just swallowing errors.

Comment: stderr is saying:['bash: curl\xa0https://www.facebook.com: No such file or directory\n']

Comment: Don't use a bare `except`, and don't hide whatever exception you *do* catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd` contains a [non-breaking space](http://www.codetable.net/hex/a0) instead of a normal space. Remove what looks like a space after the `curl` command and replace it with a real space character.